# Apollo: Push() method causing component to unmount on optimisticResponse update in Mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Can Anyone hazard a guess as to why the following optimisticResponse/update code (question continues after code):

AddToCart.js

```html
const ADD_TO_CART_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation addToCart($id: ID!) {
    addToCart(id: $id) {
      id
      quantity
    }
  }
`;

class AddToCart extends React.Component {
  outOfStock(){
    alert('This item is out of stock.');
  };
  
  update = (cache, { data: { addToCart } }) => {
    const data = cache.readQuery({ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY });
    data.me.cart.push(addToCart);
    cache.writeQuery({ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY, data });
  };
  
  render() {
    const { id, quantity, title, image, price } = this.props;
    return (
      <Mutation
        mutation={ADD_TO_CART_MUTATION}
        variables={{
          id,
        }}
        optimisticResponse={{
          __typename: 'Mutation',
          addToCart: {
            __typename: 'CartItem',
            id: '-1',
            quantity: 1,
            item: {
              __typename: 'Item',
              id,
              price,
              image,
              title,
              description: 'test',
              mainDescription: 'test',
              quantity,
            }
          }
        }}
        update={this.update}
        refetchQueries={[{ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY }, { query: ALL_ITEMS_QUERY }]}
      >
        {(addToCart, { loading }) => {
          if (quantity >= 1) {
            return (<button disabled={loading} onClick={() => {
              addToCart().catch(err => alert(err.message));
            }}>
              Add{loading && 'ing'} To Cart 
            </button>)
          } else {
            return (<button>
              Out of Stock 
            </button>)
          }
        }}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }
}

export default AddToCart;
```

AddToCart parent component (Item.js)

```html
export default class Item extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    return (
      <User>
        {({ data: { me } }) => {
          let hasPerms;
          hasPerms = (me && me === null) ? false : (me && me.permissions.some(permission => ['ADMIN'].includes(permission)));
          return (
          <ItemStyles>
            {item.image && <img src={item.image} alt={item.title} />}
            <Title>
              <Link
                href={{
                  pathname: '/item',
                  query: { id: item.id },
                }}
              >
                <a>{item.title}</a>
              </Link>
            </Title>
            <PriceTag>{formatMoney(item.price)}</PriceTag>
            <p>{item.description} { (item.quantity <= 10 && item.quantity !== 0) && `- (${item.quantity} in stock)` }</p>
            <div className="buttonList">
              <AddToCart id={item.id} quantity={item.quantity} image={item.image} title={item.title} price={item.price} />
              {hasPerms && (
              <>
              <Link
                href={{
                  pathname: 'update',
                  query: { id: item.id },
                }}
              >
                <a>Edit ✏️</a>
              </Link>
              <DeleteItem id={item.id}>Delete This Item</DeleteItem>
              </>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="buttonList">
            </div>
          </ItemStyles>
          );
        }}
      </User>
    );
  }
}
```

Item parent (Items.js)

```html
class Items extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Center>
        <Pagination page={this.props.page} />
        <Query
          query={ALL_ITEMS_QUERY}
          variables={{
            skip: this.props.page * perPage - perPage,
          }}
        >
          {({ data, error, loading }) => {
            if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
            if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
            return (
              <ItemsList>{data.items.map((item, i) => <Item item={item} key={item.id}></Item>)}</ItemsList>
            );
          }}
        </Query>
        <Pagination page={this.props.page} />
      </Center>
    );
  }
}

export default Items;
```

causes my UI to rerender (component unmounts) after adding an item to an empty cart (See instructions to replicate)?

1. Go to https://flamingo-next-production.herokuapp.com.
2. login using, Username: `testing123@123.com`, Password:`testing123`.
3. click 'My cart' link and delete any items in there. Leave cart window open.
4. click `Shop` link and add an item. Observe the open cart window/UI after you have clicked add (You may have to wait a few moments before observing change).

Why does this happen and what's the best way to rectify it??

Comment: I think the problem is either in your <Stock/> component, or from its parent. Could you share the code for both?

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with your code. It looks like at the return of the `addToCart` operation, the apollo's internal cache is emptied, which make `user.data.me` equals to null, and your `Cart` component returns null. If you remove the `update` attribute of your mutation, does it still do this?

Comment: @Errorname No. Everything functions correctly with update removed, in that there is no re-rendering that is.

Comment: And what if you keep the `update` attribute, but remove the `optimisticResponse` attribute?

Comment: @Errorname Then we're back to square 1 again, the component re-renders.

Comment: @Errorname It looks like this may be an issue: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2617

Comment: That's quite possible. What happens if you comment `data.me.cart.push(addToCart);`?

Comment: @Errorname Commenting out push() enables the item to be added to the cart, without the added side effect of the component un-mounting. But doing so acts as if the whole premise for optimisticResponse existing ceases, as there is a noticeable delay between clicking `Add to cart` and the item appearing in the cart.